# Take conditions from spinner and retrieve and list data in listview from database on basis of that conditions

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to retrieve data from the database so that only those data should be listview which will work on the true condition. 
I have added two spinners in the XML file. One spinner contains the default values stored in java file for getting options of blood group and second contains city names. 
I want that if a user selects BloodGroup as O+ve from spinner and City as Gurgaon and clicks on search button then the details of the person will be shown in the listview that follows both spinner queries.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? What have you tried so far to achieve the described behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The following is a working example of how you can apply the **SelectedItem** from two spinners and then by clicking a Search button display only rows that contain both items are then listed (if any).

The examples are based upon the scenario you provide. That is there is a specific list of Cities and BloodGroups that can be selected via the Spinners. The records table includes columns for both plus two columns **_id** and **name**. The test database is populated with 100 random names, cities and bloodgroups.

The layout **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blood Bank" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/select_bloodgroup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/select_city"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </Spinner>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/records_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The DatabaseHelper **DBHelper.java**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "bloodbank";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_RECORDS = "records";
    public static final String COl_RECORDS_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_RECORDS_NAME = "_name";
    public static final String COL_RECORDS_BLOODGROUP = "_blood_group";
    public static final String COL_RECORDS_CITY = "_city";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crtrecords = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                TB_RECORDS + "(" +
                COl_RECORDS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL_RECORDS_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COL_RECORDS_CITY + " TEXT, " +
                COL_RECORDS_BLOODGROUP + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crtrecords);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addRecord(String name, String city, String bloodgroup) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_RECORDS_NAME,name);
        cv.put(COL_RECORDS_CITY,city);
        cv.put(COL_RECORDS_BLOODGROUP,bloodgroup);
        return mDB.insert(TB_RECORDS,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getrecords(String city, String bloodgroup) {
        ArrayList<String> baseargs = new ArrayList<>();
        String whereclause = null;
        if (city != null && city.length() > 0) {
            whereclause = COL_RECORDS_CITY + "=?";
            baseargs.add(city);
        }
        if (bloodgroup != null && bloodgroup.length() > 0) {
            if (whereclause != null && whereclause.length() > 0) {
                whereclause = whereclause + " AND ";
            } else whereclause = "";
            whereclause = whereclause + COL_RECORDS_BLOODGROUP + "=?";
            baseargs.add(bloodgroup);
        }
        String[] whereargs = null;
        if (baseargs.size() > 0) {
            whereargs = new String[baseargs.size()];
            for (int i =0; i < baseargs.size();i++) {
                whereargs[i] = baseargs.get(i);
            }
        }
        return mDB.query(TB_RECORDS,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,COL_RECORDS_NAME);
    }
}
```

The invoking activity **MainActivity.java** :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Specific Blood groups
    public static final String[] BLOODGROUPS = new String[]{
            "A+","A-","B+","B-","0+","0-","AB+","AB-"
    };

    //Specific Cities
    public static final String[] CITIES = new String[]{
            "London","Paris","New York","Montreal","Gurgaon"
    };

    // Some names for auto generation of test data
    static final String[] peoples_names = new String[]{
            "Fred","Mary","Bert","Anne","James","Susan","Tom","Theresa",
            "Cherles","Corrine","David","Diana","Edward","Esmerelda",
            "George","Gorgina","Harrold","Heather"

    };

    TextView mTitle;
    Spinner mBloodGroups, mCities;
    Button mSearch;
    DBHelper mDBHlpr;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mCitiesAdapter, mBloodGroupsAdapater;
    ListView mRecordsList;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    String mCurrentCities = "", mCurrentBloodGroups = "";
    Cursor mCsr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = this.findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBloodGroups = this.findViewById(R.id.select_bloodgroup);
        mCities = this.findViewById(R.id.select_city);
        mSearch = this.findViewById(R.id.search);
        mRecordsList = this.findViewById(R.id.records_list);
        mCurrentCities = "";
        mCurrentBloodGroups = "";

        // Add some test data
        mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase(),DBHelper.TB_RECORDS) < 1) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                mDBHlpr.addRecord(
                        peoples_names[rnd.nextInt(peoples_names.length)],
                        CITIES[rnd.nextInt(CITIES.length)],
                        BLOODGROUPS[rnd.nextInt(BLOODGROUPS.length)]
                );
            }
        }

        //Setup City Spinner
        mCitiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,CITIES);
        mCities.setAdapter(mCitiesAdapter);
        //Setup Bloodgroups Spinner
        mBloodGroupsAdapater = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,BLOODGROUPS);
        mBloodGroups.setAdapter(mBloodGroupsAdapater);
        // Add Search Buitton Click Listener
        mSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mCurrentCities = mCities.getSelectedItem().toString();
                mCurrentBloodGroups = mBloodGroups.getSelectedItem().toString();
                refreshList();
            }
        });
        // Initial List (All)
        refreshList();

    }

    //Setup or refresh the ListView
    private void refreshList() {
        // Grab the data
        mCsr = mDBHlpr.getrecords(mCurrentCities,mCurrentBloodGroups);
        // If first time then setup the Cursor Adapter
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    mCsr,
                    new String[]{DBHelper.COL_RECORDS_NAME,DBHelper.COL_RECORDS_CITY},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            mRecordsList.setAdapter(mSCA);
        }
        // If not first time then swap the cursor
        else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

Initially the following is displayed (as the data is random generated it may differ although there will be 100 item listed) :-

[image]

After Selecting City Gurgaon :- (note results will likely differ due to random data) :-

[image]

After Selecting Bloodgroup A- :- (again results will likely differ) :-

[image]

- Note this example works, the intention is that you learn from the supplied code and do YOUR research, if you have subsequent questions then you should ask them as separate and distinct questions on Stack Overflow.